# Hash::check() returns false when provided correct credentials

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Using seeded user credentials, I cannot log in to my site with this code:

```
public function doLogin(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::whereUsername($request->username)->first();

    if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        Auth::login($user, true);
        return redirect('/headquarters');
    } else {

        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

It was working just fine last night. Since then I have refreshed the migration, which may have triggered something weird somewhere.

The routes, for the curious:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Route::group(['middleware' => ''], function() {

    Route::get('/sandbox', 'SandboxController@index');

    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'IndexController@index']);
    Route::get('/login', ['uses' => 'HomeController@showLogin']);
    Route::post('/login', ['uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin']);
    Route::get('/logout', ['uses' => 'HomeController@doLogout']);
```

What am I doing wrong? I've cleared route and composer caches, just in case, and could literally copy and paste the credentials from the seeder and still fail.

Printing the data on the login screen yields the following:

```
input password is: asdf
input username is: naltroc

$user is : App\Models\User Object
(
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => username
            [1] => email
            [2] => password
            [3] => cash
            [4] => has_fights_pending
            [5] => active_character
            [6] => created_at
            [7] => updated_at
        )

    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => password
            [1] => remember_token
        )

    [connection:protected] => 
    [table:protected] => 
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [incrementing] => 1
    [timestamps] => 1
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [username] => naltroc
            [email] => t@mail.com
            [password] => $2y$10$8s2luMe5zKglh0cKr0tdjeBdi5.Y6iClBKnVKJc5/bW
            [has_fights_pending] => 0
            [active_character] => 
            [cash] => 42
            [prestige] => 0
            [notoriety] => 0
            [remember_token] => 
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [username] => naltroc
            [email] => t@mail.com
            [password] => $2y$10$8s2luMe5zKglh0cKr0tdjeBdi5.Y6iClBKnVKJc5/bW
            [has_fights_pending] => 0
            [active_character] => 
            [cash] => 42
            [prestige] => 0
            [notoriety] => 0
            [remember_token] => 
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 
        )
```

Comment: I would say you request password wrong or empty. can you dd $request->password and check if it returns correct value ?

Comment: That's what you see at the top of the third box of code, the request value for username and password.

Comment: How do you save the password in the seeder? `Hash::make('asdf')`?

Comment: @EddyTheDove, exactly.

Comment: I think he saves with `Hash::make` based on dump he posted. But I am saying your password is wrong for sure it returns false! I mean its not a code related unless you override `Hash::check  ` 

try this 
`dd(Hash::check('test1234','$2y$10$QM1oFHJMm21jdSoBZPGL7O1Y6iCoenqaak2.cWZDdhBO84svieTxO'));`

Answer (score 0):

Hey simply follow the doc

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing

If not working then please update the password in database & then try again.

Set the password by using below method

```
Hash::make("NewPassword");//set the return text in DB
```

Also test the value of `$request->password`

```
dd($request->password);
```